# Build an array using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this array:

```
$arrUsers = array(
    array('username' => 'admin', 'password' => 'admin123')
);
```

I just want to build a similar copy of this array using data from PDO MySQL Table, with foreach.. I've tried this, but doesn't work

```
$arrUsers = array();
foreach ($users as $i){
    array_push($arrUsers, array('username' => $i['username'], 'password' => $i['password']));
}
```

returns a different array structure..

--EDITED:
MY PDO CODE

```
$sql_buscaUsuarios = "SELECT username, password FROM users";

    try{
        $query_buscaUsuarios = $conecta->prepare($sql_buscaUsuarios);
        $query_buscaUsuarios -> execute();
        $usuarios = $query_buscaUsuarios->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
    catch(PDOexception $erro_buscaEndereco){
        echo 'er2'.$erro_buscaEndereco->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: How does your table looks like? and What's your PDO code?

Comment: Is that an example password or your real one?  Also, to the above comment, 'looks like' is valid.

Comment: with your code i get the same result.. http://ideone.com/dQEulP what is wrong?

Comment: These [0], [1] shouldn't to appear, you know? `Array([0] => array(..))`should be `Array(Array(..))`

Comment: Sorry, that really doesn't matter. Thanks!

Comment: It's the index, every item in the array have an index. When you do print_r it prints the index too. In your example you have an index too but you don't see it in the code. Try to print_r your $arrUsers example